# ChoiceBox in JavaFX - default title

Tags: java, javafx

I try to specify for the choicebox a "title". I tried to set the title as one of the options and set it to default. But I don't want the first option (which is the title) to appear in the list of  options.

Here's the code I used:

```java
ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<String>();
choiceBox.getItems().addAll("How old are you?", "10-20", "20-30", "30-40");
choiceBox.setId("choiceBox");
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

And here is the result:

[image: The result of the code]

In the documentation I found this, but I couldn't figure out how to specify the selected item to be something that is not in the options list

[ChoiceBox (JavaFX 11)](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html)

By default, the ChoiceBox has no item selected unless otherwise specified. Although the ChoiceBox will only allow a user to select from the predefined list, **it is possible for the developer to specify the selected item to be something other than what is available in the predefined list**. This is required for several important use cases.

Comment: A [ComboBox](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) has the option to set a prompt text. It sounds like this suits your needs better than a ChoiceBox in this case.

Comment: add all the choosable options, then set its value to the uncontained sentence

Comment: @kleopatra setting another value doesn't show it when the `ChoiceBox` is not open.

Comment: @M.S. hmm ... would consider such behavior a bug

Comment: @M.S. actually it _is_ a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087555 - reported 2014 by .. me ;) Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @kleopatra I bet it felt so nice when you found it. I posted a workaround.

Comment: the fix is integrated, will be available in fx15 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChoiceBoxSkin<T>` shows the value of the selected item in a `Label`. Unfortunately, this label is private. If you have a reason to not use `ComboBox<T>`, here is a workaround:

```java
ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
choiceBox.getItems().addAll("10-20", "20-30", "30-40");
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    SkinBase<ChoiceBox<String>> skin = (SkinBase<ChoiceBox<String>>) choiceBox.getSkin();
    // children contain only "Label label" and "StackPane openButton"
    for (Node child : skin.getChildren()) {
        if (child instanceof Label) {
            Label label = (Label) child;
            if (label.getText().isEmpty()) {
                label.setText("How old are you?");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I tried to use combobox out of curiosity, but you're right. In my situation (a particular one) I have to use choiceboxes. Your code is perfect for what I need. Thank you very much!